# ASP.NET Core MVC route based localization with areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-localization

I have created a project in ASP.NET Core and wanted the language to be detected based on the url:
https://localhost:7090/en

If controllers and actions are used in the url, everything works as planned. However, when the registration or login page is called, it does not work (default asp.net identity registration page).

Works: https://localhost:7090/en/Home/Index

Does not work: https://localhost:7090/en/Identity/Account/Register

In the startup, I configured the following for MVC routing:

```
builder.Services
    .AddLocalization()
    .AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = CultureHelper.GetSupportedCultures();
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulturne("en");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

    var provider = new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider
    {
        RouteDataStringKey = "culture",
        UIRouteDataStringKey = "culture",
        Options = options
    };
    options.RequestCultureProviders = new[] { provider };

});

builder.Services.Configure<RouteOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ConstraintMap.Add("culture", typeof(LanguageRouteConstraint));
});


var options = app.Services.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value); 
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    app.MapRazorPages();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "LocalizedDefault",
        template: "{culture:culture}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

The language constraint is then used to set the CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture.

Here is a code snippet for calling the login/register pages:

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">
        @Language.register
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">
        @Language.login
    </a>
</li>
```

I've tried pretty much everything I've found on Google, but nothing seems to work....

I just think knowing that it does not work because of the pages

**[UPDATE]**
I was able to get the url to be valid with the following code:

```
builder.Services
.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new LanguageRouteModelConversion());
 });
```

---

```
public class LanguageRouteModelConversion : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel pageRouteModel)
    {
        var selectorModels = new List<SelectorModel>();
     
        foreach (var selector in pageRouteModel.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel?.Template;
            selectorModels.Add(new SelectorModel()
            {
                AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                {
                    Template = "/{culture}/" + template
                }
            });
        }

        foreach (var model in selectorModels)
            pageRouteModel.Selectors.Add(model);
    }
}
```

But i still don't know how to call the page properly

Comment: You are using areas in your URL but do not have the mappings setup for them. Are you meaning to use areas? In your example of the failed URL, the route mapper thinks "Identity" is a controller.

Comment: No the areas are not a must, but I think it would be easier to use them since the "Identity" area already exists. Otherwise it wouldn't bother me if the area is missing in the url: https://localhost:7090/en/Account/Register

I tried to make the mapping, but every attempt failed...

Comment: I'm confused when you say the "Identity" area already exists. You need to define your mappings to match the setup in your controllers and views. The mapper is very specific on the structure you use. You'll need to give a lot more information to get a solid answer on this one.

Comment: Just to clarify, I created an ASP.NET Core project and selected "Single Accounts" as the authentication type. Now I have in the project folder the subfolder "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_ViewStart.cstml".
The pages like registration and login are not in the folder, however I can access them.
It is the scaffold item of type "identity" as far as I understand.

Now I want the url to specify the language for that page (as described above).
I tried to configure the routing for this in the startup file, but to no avail.

Comment: @CompletelyLost Is there an ```Account``` folder inside the ```page``` folder? check it.

Comment: No my Areas folder only contains "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_ViewStart.cstml"

Answer (score 0):

You said you have no `Account` folder in `Identity` directory. If so then how you do you expect `register,login` page router will work?

```
 builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<YourDbContextName>();
```

Then Scaffold Register, Login, LogOut page etc. After scaffolded, you will find a separate `Account` folder in `Pages` folder. and Your `Account` folder actually contains login,register page. It should resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.Services
.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false)
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Identity", "/", pageRouteModel =>
    {
        foreach (var selectorModel in pageRouteModel.Selectors)
            selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template = "{culture:culture}/" + selectorModel.AttributeRouteModel.Template;
    });
});
```

This did the trick for me, i finally figured it out...

Comment: Now i have seen that a new problem occurred...
I am able to call register or login but once I'm there, i cannot go back.
`
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="/de/account/register/">Register</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
`

href to all the other pages is just empty

Answer (score 0):

Add the culture param to the URL `asp-route-culture=...`

```html
@{ var culture= System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name }
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register" asp-route-culture="@culture">
        @Language.register
    </a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login" asp-route-culture="@culture">
        @Language.login
    </a>
</li>
```